# time.sleep - TypeError: A Float is Required

Tags: python

```
time.sleep('2')
TypeError: a float is required
```

How do I fix this? I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do here.

Comment: did you read the error message? did you try to google it, or to understand what a "float" is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a string (of one character `"2"`). Pass a number:

```
time.sleep(2)
```